# Return giving me a whole function, not the value

Tags: javascript, return-value

the code below is returning the following in the console:

```
[19-07-06 12:46:55:014 PDT] undefined
[19-07-06 12:46:55:015 PDT] 
function (date) {
    var cache1 = date[0];
    var cache2 = date[1];
    this.dateKey = cache1.toString().match(/[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} \d{2}/);
    this.rawTime = cache1.toString().match(/[0-99]{2}:[0-99]{2}:[0-99]{2}/);
    this.row = cache2;
    this.rawTime.toString().split(":");
    Logger.log(rTimeF);
    return rTimeF;
}

[19-07-06 12:46:55:015 PDT] NaN
[19-07-06 12:46:55:016 PDT] NaN
[19-07-06 12:46:55:016 PDT] NaN
```

dividing the task to sub functions
logging the variables at different steps

```
 //Returns an object with dateKey,rawTime and row num
   var itemHandler =function(date){
       var cache1 = date[0]
       var cache2 = date[1]
       this.dateKey = cache1.toString().match(/[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} \d{2}/);
       this.rawTime = cache1.toString().match(/[0-99]{2}:[0-99]{2}:[0-99]{2}/);
        this.row = cache2
        this.rawTime.toString().split(":")
        Logger.log(rTimeF)
        return rTimeF

  }
  var itemHandlerHelper = function(rawTime){
      Logger.log(rawTime)
      var one = (parseInt(rTimeF[1],10)*60*60)
      var two =(parseInt(rTimeF[2],10)*60)
      var three = parseInt((rTimeF))
      Logger.log(one)
      Logger.log(two)
      Logger.log(three)
  }


  var data = new rawDat("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19hRw1hVa-PTVXFT-u_K9niRdx9Om1PNjPLOIP6isCjQ/edit#gid=0","Sheet1")
  var names = new arrayParse(data.data,6)
  var finalDate = new itemHandler(names[3])
  var rTimeF = itemHandler
  itemHandlerHelper(rTimeF)
```

the last three logs (one two and three) should display numbers instead they display NaN

The log before those should return the value for the finaldate instance of itemHandler : rTimeF instead it returns the whole function

Comment: do you have a target for this? `this.rawTime.toString().split(":");`

Comment: `var rTimeF = itemHandler` — that statement creates a variable called "rTimeF" whose value is a reference to that function. It's not at all clear what you expect that code to do.

Comment: Also `itemHandlerHelper()` does not use its parameter other than to produce a log entry; what is the the parameter supposed to do?

Comment: fixed the issue with this.rawTime.toString().split(":"); not having a target now it is returning "TypeError: Cannot find function itemHandlerHelper in object function (date) {...}. (line 44, file "Code")" even though its clearly defined above.

Comment: itemHandlerHelper is being hoisted as undefined. Try defining it as: function itemHandlerHelper(rawTime){} instead.

Comment: Also, you have basically aliased itemHandler in rTimeF. You probably meant to do: var rTimeF = itemHandler(some date);